# Is there any way to add custom images as icons to ballon tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Currently I'm getting only four options to add as icons to ballon tooltip. How can I add my own images as an icon.

Comment: In case you are willing/able to spend some money you can buy a component like [SuperTooltip for WinForms](https://www.componentone.com/Studio/Navigation-Layout/SuperTooltipWinForms)